USB CD-ROM drive not working with Fujitsu Stylistic 3400
I had a Fujitsu Stylistic 3400 that was lying upstairs for a very long time. One day, I decided to take it downstairs and try using it with the LG portable DVD drive I got from my dad. I decided to try installing an OS on the tablet using the CD drive. I inserted a Windows 98 CD into the USB CD-ROM drive. However, after booting from the boot disk, the system did not detect the CD-ROM. I tried to get the computer to read the disc manually, but however, it did not detect the disc. Any solutions on how to get the computer to read my USB CD-ROM drive?

You can try copying the CD manually to the hard drive and installing from there IIRC.

(cont...) good luck finding that ISO and a decent diskette to write it to. Unfortunately those products were never user friendly for installing/reinstalling the OS, they're designed to work "as is" with the factory install. They were designed to be "simple", not to be fiddled with. You may have better luck with a newer Windows generation. Although not officially supported, WinXP should work better than the prior versions. Anything newer than that probably won't work. Linux is a much better choice but the choices are strictly limited to very niche distros but yes, most are up-to-date (...)

(cont...) in terms of security, unlike any Windows still capable of running on that thing (WinXP is out-of-support for more than a decade now and absolutely SHOULDN'T be used online). 4. Here's a fairly contemporary experience with the same machine: https://davwheat.github.io/fujitsu-stylistic-3400/ Note the blogger confirming despite having a single USB 1.1 port, the device does not support USB boot

Can you remove the hard drive, connect it to a different machine and install Windows 98 on it? You do not say how old (or new) the USB drive is. The likelihood of the machine being able to recognize the drive is possibly asking too much of the technology; in 2003 I bought an external USB CD drive after the internal one in my machine failed and the drive never worked because it needed USB 2.0 and my machine only had USB 1.1 support.

As an aside, I used to have a very old Toshiba netbook and it came with an external drive that used a PCMCIA card for the connection rather than USB, so that might work if you can find a cheap one. Also, my guess is your machine will be worth good money in a few years so hang on to it!

The bios must support booting on usb. Seems like this one doesn’t?!

I don't think BIOS boot is required.  Windows 9x came with a boot floppy.  The system booted from floppy does however need drivers to read the CD-ROM with the installation files.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, my tablet does not support booting from USB because old BIOS versions didn't support booting from anything USB.

Windows 98 boot floppy disk has no understanding of USB subsystem of any kind. It only comes with drivers for a few types of CD drives, standard IDE/ATAPI drives and a couple of different SCSI drive types.
Which also means, if you happen to have a bootable install CD, even if your BIOS supports booting from an USB CD drive, after the CD boots with the bootable floppy image, there are no drivers to see the contents of the CD data partition with install files.

Yeah. The simplest way to resolve that is to use whatever means you can (eg. a suitably old Damn Small Linux with a boot floppy, either native or something like Plop) to boot into an environment which can see both the USB CD and the hard drive, copy the install files into a folder on C:, then boot the DOS/Windows boot disk and install from there. Once you've got Win98SE installed and booted, drivers for USB optical drives are available.

@ssokolow Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this while installing Windows XP on the tablet using this method. It worked perfectly.
